# What would an effective means be of protecting a habitat from UV-C radiation?

Tags: habitat, humans

We are lucky on Earth, the ozone layer protects us from UV-C by absorbing wavelengths below about 280nm.  However, the same can not be said for in space and on places like Luna and Mars.  I would imagine that generating and sustaining an artificial ozone layer would not be feasible.

What materials would provide adequate protection from UV-C, while allowing UV-B (needed for vitamin D production) to penetrate into a habitat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glasses can be manufactured such that they transmits the desired parts of the UV.

Looking at the picture below (found [here](http://www.shimadzu.com/an/industry/ceramicsmetalsmining/chem0501005.htm)), together with a somewhat official definition of [ultraviolet wavelength ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet):

- UVA: 400-315 nm
- UVB: 315-280 nm
- UVC: 280-100 nm

[image]

it is clear that most ordinary glasses are mostly opaque to UVC, and start being partially transparent from UVB up.

From that same wiki page:

> Ordinary glass is partially transparent to UVA but is opaque to
>   shorter wavelengths, whereas silica or quartz glass, depending on
>   quality, can be transparent even to vacuum UV wavelengths.

A mixture of various glass types (possibly with coatings) can thus be manufactured to allow any desired portion of UVA, UVB and UVC through.